# I need to multiply two column (A1 * B1) and the answer present at B2 then multiply the A2 value * B2 value

Tags: postgresql

I have paste the details as below,

The detailed requirements are here:

[image: The detailed sheet attached please click here]

```
Sno     Column A        Column B        Column C        Formula
1       0 -1 Yrs        0.963190184     100000      
2       1-4 Yrs         0.992394232     96319       (B1 * C1 (default value 100000)) =C2
3       5 - 9 Yrs       0.994964922     95586       (B2 * C2 ) =C3
4       10 - 14 Yrs     0.998372661     95105       (B3 * C3 ) =C4
5       15 - 19 Yrs     0.994485603     94950       
6       20- 24 Yrs      0.992903887     94427       
7       25 - 29 Yrs     0.994008987     93757       
8       30 - 34 Yrs     0.994041445     93195       
9       35 - 39 Yrs     0.991283828     92640       
10      40 - 44 Yrs     0.987141228     91832
```

The above same formula needs to be apply for the remaining columns through a PostgreSQL query.

Comment: Hi, This is not someone else homework. I am working in Goverment Public health deparment. I have creating database for population health registry. For that pupose I have writing query while reach this session I have some doubts that why I have posted my reqeust in this forum.

Comment: I see. Is what you posted a database table? Is there a column `sno` that determines the ordering (database tables as such have no ordering)?

Comment: Yes, I have attached the sample one. I will paste the orginal columns ASAP and explain what I want in this regards

Comment: Hi @LaurenzAlbe                                                                                                          I want paste my queires to see you How can I present that. I am unable to paste my sql query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your basic requirement is looking back to the prior row the lag function first comes to mind. However this dos not work as the necessary value is being calculated of the fly and lag operates on the result set (prior to lag operation). So we turn to a recursive query where at each recursion we have available the just calculated on the prior recursion. This of course assumes the other columns are already loaded. We get the desired values with:

```
with recursive demo( rno, r_colb, r_colc) as 
     ( select 0, 1::numeric,  100000::numeric    -- prime the recursion 
       union all 
       select sno, column_b,  r_colb*r_colc
        from test 
        join demo  
          on (sno = rno+1)                       -- next sno  
     )
select rno, r_colb, round(r_colc) r_colc
  from demo ;
```

That does not get to the final need - updating the table. Fortunately, Postgres supports "update ... from (subquery) where ..." structure and the subquery just basically needs to be a valid query; including the above. So we arrive at:

```
update test 
   set column_c = r_colc
  from (
        with recursive demo( rno, r_colb, r_colc) as 
             ( select 0, 1::numeric,  100000::numeric    -- prime the recursion 
               union all 
               select sno, column_b,  r_colb*r_colc
                from test 
                join demo  
                  on (sno = (select min(sno)             -- since I do trust autogenerated ids 
                               from test                 -- to actually be in perfect sequence
                              where sno > rno))    
             )
        select rno, r_colb, round(r_colc) r_colc
          from demo 
        ) s
  where sno = rno;
```

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=126595a750d0a80810846fa96a87b561) run in v9.6.

---

In response to "applied for continuous calculation", yes that is possible and actually only changing the WITH clause to prime the recursion. But first, when speaking on SQL remove IF from your vocabulary - there is no such thing. There are conditionals (where, case, when...) but ***no IF***.  
The non-recursive query just gets the last known value then the recursive part looks at each subsequent and calculates column_c from it. To restart the calculation, just do the same.  I modified the update query to do just that. See revised [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=c03f881de519e00d16bac7d874a6d377). It would have been possible to just modify the non-recursive query to select sno 10 (the last known value for column_c). But doing so would require updating the query for subsequent execution. Instead it looks for the last know (not null column_c) selecting that as the primer. This does require all new rows leave column_c null. But it should be good for any number of additional rows.  
Note: The term "prime/primer" is *my terminology for this query*. It is **not** a general technical term used with a recursive CTE.

```
update test     
   set column_c = r_colc   
  from (
        with recursive demo( rno, r_colb, r_colc) as 
             ( select sno, column_b, column_c    -- prime the recursion 
                 from test 
                where sno = (select max(sno)
                               from test 
                              where column_c is not null 
                            ) 
               union all 
               select sno, column_b,  r_colb*r_colc
                from test 
                join demo  
                  on (sno = (select min(sno)             -- since I do trust autogenerated ids 
                               from test                 -- to actually be in perfect sequence
                              where sno > rno))    
             )
        select rno, r_colb, round(r_colc) r_colc
          from demo 
        ) s
```

where sno = rno;

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much. I have modified my actual query based on this above query. Now I have got a proper result

Comment: If this solved your issue then please accept the answer. This helps future questioners that have the same or similar issues.

Comment: Hi Belayer, Thank you so much.I need some clarifications, The same column_A parameters again starts from 11th rows if its possible WHERE condition or IF condition may be applied for continuous calculation. Orelse we need to splitup the tables and calculate.

Comment: Yes you can continue the calculation. See revisions to answer.

Comment: Hi Belayer, Sorry, I have missed somethings.I have already put default value like 100000 for all the 0-1 Years rows .Totally 32 sets (Each set Starts from 0-1 Years and end with 80 and above Years) so I have update the 0-1 Years default value  via UPDATE query " update test set column_b=100000 where column_a='0-1 Year' ". So once the 80 and above years completed then again starts from 0-1 Years with default value 10000 in the column_b.

Comment: Hi Belayer, The first answer acepted for only one SET. I have 32 SETS I need to continuosly multiply all the SETS. Each SET have default value 100000 for 0-1 Years

Comment: Hi @belayer sorry to take your time

Comment: Look at the 2 versions. You will see that the recursive CTE does all the calculation. The first establishes the default value for the upcoming row; running just the CTE without the update statement will show this. You should be able to modify the recursive part an detect if it needs the calculation to "restart" or continue (Hint  substring on olumn_a), If restart needed output the default value and (do not increment sno).

Comment: Hi Belayer, Thank you for your support.I have tried but error came. I am totally new to this environment. Please show one sample demo I will follow up the same for future references.

Comment: Telling me you got an error is completely useless. Tell me exactly what error (the complete error message) you got, and your exact query, that can get you an answer.