# In Postgresql need to calculate the two rows values column_d2=(column_c2 * 0.3) + (column_c3 * 0.7) ? via update function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have created one table like "test" and inserted the values in the columns

```
create table test( Sno       integer 
                 , Column_A   text
                 , Column_B   numeric
                 , Column_C   numeric
                 ) ;
                 
           
insert into test (sno, Column_A, Column_B) 
     (values (1 ,'0 -1 Yrs',     0.963190184)     
           , (2 ,'1-4 Yrs',      0.992394232)     
           , (3 ,'5 - 9 Yrs',    0.994964922)     
           , (4 ,'10 - 14 Yrs',  0.998372661)     
           , (5 ,'15 - 19 Yrs',  0.994485603)     
           , (6 ,'20- 24 Yrs',   0.992903887)     
           , (7 ,'25 - 29 Yrs',  0.994008987)     
           , (8 ,'30 - 34 Yrs',  0.994041445)     
           , (9 ,'35 - 39 Yrs',  0.991283828)     
           , (10,'40 - 44 Yrs',  0.987141228) 
     ); 


select * from test; 
  
alter table test add column column_d bigint; ----adding a new column

update test
   set column_c = r_colc
  from (
        with recursive demo( rno, r_colb, r_colc) as 
             ( select 0, 1::numeric,  100000::numeric  -- prime the recursion 
               union all 
               select sno, column_b,  r_colb*r_colc
                from test 
                join demo  
                  on (sno = (select min(sno)          -- since I do trust autogenerated ids 
                               from test              -- to actually be in perfect sequence
                              where sno > rno))    
             )
        select rno, r_colb, round(r_colc) r_colc
          from demo 
        ) s
  where sno = rno; 
  

select * from test;
```

Now I need to calculate the two rows values column_d2=(column_c2 * 0.3) + (column_c3 * 0.7) ? via update function

[TABLE DETAILS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnb3W.png)

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=b5bbd37ce0ea5893d136df5be05dd281

Comment: I have attached the table details image format

Comment: the Headline doesn't match the text at the bottom and the query doesn't match both (don't see a 0.3 or a 0.7) Please clarify your question

Comment: Hi @Turo, I need to multiply the column value with default value(0.3 & 0.7) and add the multipled values then print the result in the another columns. I have attached the tables details for your kind reference.

Comment: Hi @Turo, I have edited the headline

Comment: I still don't understand, but i'd say make it a stored procedure and loop over the records

Comment: Hi, did u see my table attached

Comment: I am just lost.  Nothing in the data is called `column_2` or `column_3`.

Comment: This is a continuation from your [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67224350/i-need-to-multiply-two-column-a1-b1-and-the-answer-present-at-b2-then-multip) and you have just populated data for this one with my answer. **DO NOT do this on future questions.** Take the time to populate the new question freshly. It should not take more than a couple minuets. But given that experience I think I know what you want. ***But you must clearly define what you want***.  @GordonLinoff I think he means: column_c2  (column_c from row 2) and column_c3  (column_c from row 3).  We will see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a simple update, assuming the column meaning in my comment is correct. Use the LEAD window function to get the value for the column from the next row. Then the update is a simple multiplication:

```
update test t  
   set column_d = (cr*.3 + crn*.7)::bigint
  from (select sno, column_c cr, lead(column_c) over(order by sno) crn from test) s
 where t.sno = s.sno 
   and t.column_a not like '0%';
```

Note: *cr* is column_c for current row and *crn* is current roe next row. But that obviously begs the question: What do you do for the new column_d when there in no next row.

Comment: Hi @Belayer, First of all very thank you for your greatful support in this forum. And I am really sorry to do that, I will not done in future. I will explained, Each column_d row have separate calculation. For example in first column_d (rows 2) =(0.3*Column_c(row 2) + 0.7* Column_c(row 3) --- for Column_a 0-1 Yrs  and next column_d (row 3)=(4/7) * (Column_c(row 3) + Column_c(row 4) --- for Column_a 1-4 Yrs and next Column_d (row 4) = (5/2)*(Column_c (row 4) + Column_c (row 5)) --- for Column_a 5-9 Yrs to 35-39 Yrs

Comment: and last Column_d(row 11) =Column_c/another field value ----For Column_a 80 and Above Yrs.

Comment: Hi @Belayer, I have completed the task based on your "update" query. Now I have alter the table column_e

Comment: how to i paste my sql query in this forum

Comment: update life_expectancy_vellore t 
   set no_of_person_years_lived = (startlifer*0.3+ startlifern*0.7)::bigint
  from (select id, startlife startlifer, lead(startlife) over(order by id) startlifern from life_expectancy_vellore) s
 where t.id=s.id 
   and t.age_range='0-1 Years';

Comment: update life_expectancy_vellore l 
   set no_of_person_years_lived =(2*startlifer+startlifern)::bigint
  from (select id, startlife startlifer,lead(startlife) over(order by id) startlifern from life_expectancy_vellore) s
 where l.id = s.id 
   and l.age_range='1-4 Years';

Comment: update life_expectancy_vellore v 
   set no_of_person_years_lived =(2.5*startlifer+startlifern)::bigint
  from (select id, startlife startlifer,lead(startlife) over(order by id) startlifern from life_expectancy_vellore) s
 where v.id = s.id 
   and v.age_range in('5-9 Years','10-14 Years','15-19 Years','20-24 Years','25-29 Years',
   '30-34 Years','35-39 Years','40-44 Years','45-49 Years','50-54 Years','55-59 Years',
   '60-64 Years','65-69 Years','70-74 Years','75-79 Years');

Comment: update life_expectancy_vellore set no_of_person_years_lived=((startlife)/(asdr)) where age_range='80 and Above';

Comment: The life_expectancy_vellore is my original table name. the table contains the below columns                                                                                                       "id"
"phr_makkal_district"
"age_range"
"count"
"femaledeath"
"asdr"
"probdying"
"probsurv"
"startlife"
"no_of_person_years_lived"
"total_person_years_lived"
"expectation_life"

Comment: now I have altered the table column "total_person_years_lived" like column_e. In this column_e need to calculate in reverse method. For example Column_e(row 11) ="need to print the Column_d same value" ---for Column_a (age_range)='80 and Above'. and then the remaining columns need to be adding reverse method from row 11 to row 2. For example Column_e (row 10) = Column_d (row 10) + Column_e (row 11) the formula need to be apply until row 2 in Column_e